# What are the right steps to deploy a Laravel 9 app to Google App Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, laravel-9

I want to deploy my Laravel 9 app (without docker) to App Engine, and I would like it to use Google Storage and Google MySql.

Comment: **no luck** is not a technical problem description. Edit your question with details.

Comment: You're right but I really mean it. I just want to know if Stackoverflow community has a link to some article explaining in clear steps (production quality): how to deploy a laravel 9 app to app engine. I already googled a lot, trust me, there's nothing out there!

Comment: The first problem you will have is PHP 8 support which Laravel 9 requires. There is a public preview https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/pull/1613/files. Other than that, most Laravel 8 docs for App Engine will apply. As far as Cloud SQL MySQL, that is supported. In regards to using Cloud Storage, that is something you would set up in Laravel. https://www.codemag.com/Article/2111071/Beginner%E2%80%99s-Guide-to-Deploying-PHP-Laravel-on-the-Google-Cloud-Platform

Comment: Note: of all the Google services, I prefer to deploy Laravel on Compute Engine. If you prefer App Engine, choose Flexible so that you can SSH into the environment.

Comment: thanks. app engine now supports `runtime: php81`

Comment: Public Preview is not the same as supported.

Comment: can you share a tuto article about "deploy Laravel on Compute Engine"? thanks

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @JohnHanley, `PHP 8.1` is currently available under **"Public Preview."** for `App Engine`.

Additionally, I found this [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/170766508#comment76) and the **Google Support team** mentioned that they will provide more information regarding `PHP 8.1` runtime within 1 month (which may include docs for deploying `Laravel 9` to `App Engine`).

I suggest to **monitor** the said public issue tracker link.